# Why do these two similar recursive C-codes give different outputs?

Tags: c, recursion, parameters, parameter-passing

I've been thinking about it for hours...

I try to explain it, but if you feel it's not clear, just try my codes...

The first code follows i = 1,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3, and c follows 0-->1-->2-->3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int c = 0;
void func (int a){
    c = a + 1;
    printf("%d", c+100);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i );
        if (c <= 2){
            func(c);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    func(c);
    return 0;
}
```

The second code follows i = 1,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3...(39 i in total), and c follows 0-->1-->2-->3-->2-->3-->2-->3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int c = 0;
void func (int c){
    c = c + 1;
    printf("%d", c+100);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i );
        if (c <= 2){
            func(c);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    func(c);
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is parameter in func(), namely "void func (int a)" and "c = a + 1".

Could you explain the reason why in the first code the "c" behave as a global variable, but in the second code after "c" becomes 3 it can still jump back to 2 and lead to a further recursion.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In the second you *shadow* the global variable `c`, you have *two different and distinct* variables named `c` inside the function. And there is *no* way to access the global variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare the parameter `int c` in the second `func`, it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `c`, so all further changes within the scope of the function only apply to the local `c` instead of the global one.